# Running soffice (libreoffice or openoffice) from command line in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application which I would like to use libreoffice to batch convert files to html. I have the following method:

```
def set_versioned_odt
  condition = %x(soffice --invisible --convert-to html /path/to/file.odt --outdir /path/to/dir/)

  if condition
    Rails.logger.info "This has been finished"
  else
    Rails.logger.info "This failed..."
  end
```

end

When I run this method in the application. It will return a failing statement; however, if I run this command in the rails console, soffice will process correctly. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in the rails app?

Thanks.

Comment: you can try convert_office gem,https://github.com/amardaxini/convert_office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess is that `soffice` isn't in the path. try specifying the full path to `soffice`.

Comment: I tried that then and now it return false when using the system method. It's strange because it works in the rails console just not in the application..

Comment: what Operating system? is the application running as a different user. If linux is something like SELinux getting in the way?

Comment: Currently I am on Mac OSX 10.8.
I checked the Path variable for the application and it seemed that it wasn't there -> ENV["PATH"]. I added it to the enviroment.rb file and got an error that was signal 6  -> SIGIOT 6.

Comment: @Kyle how did you do it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, when I called soffice, I actually had to do the particular path to it. So I had to define the location of soffice in a config file and then call it as "#{config.path_to_soffice}/soffice" and then it worked.